# I am running a big sql query and have a Compilation memory exhausted error, will increasing the warehouse size be enough?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For a project I'm working on, I have to execute a huge query (near ten thousands lines), we're running it on an xs warehouse, and I was wondering if increasing the size of the warehouse for this query particularly would avoid getting this error? Or are we going to **have** to optimize the query ?

We'd rather optimize the query after we get this one working for demonstration purpose

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the exact output of the error message? 1000 lines of SQL code is not normally a problem. There's a 1Mb limit for SQL statements, but the error you'd get for that is worded differently.

Comment: We had previously running SQL start trigging "complication memory exhausted" error in 2019. We opened a Sev-2 support case and it was resolved within 24 hours. But no complication is not related to the execution warehouse size, as it's running on shared infrastructure

Comment: Hi ! Thank you both for your comments, I edited my question because the number was not correct, we have ten thousands of lines of code. The error is no more because we HAD to optimize the query

Comment: You can also run into this error when you have logical errors in query. I missed some conditions on my left joins and hit this error (due to this my query would have resulted in very large number or rows).

Comment: This [answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76869341/4606130) @Fieldy was very useful. Recommended batching checking `getOption("odbc.batch_rows")`. This is normally set to NULL but batching into large blocks can help beat this compilation error. Do this with say `options(odbc.batch_rows = 500000)`. @Fieldy also has PUT code if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue to to break up the SQL statement into smaller sequential pieces.  Write out the intermediate results to a table, and then read that into the second query.
I have hit this issue with large, complicated SQL queries, and breaking up the query always resolved the issue.  It is unlikely that increasing the warehouse size will solve the issue.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer ! We had to do it eventually, we're still thinking of the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You might have just hit the 1 MB per statement limit on the query text size. Therefore, nothing to do with the Virtual Warehouse size.
Please check this out: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-size-limits.html
Just out of interest, how long does it take to return the error message?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer ! I think I indeed hit the query text size, running it in a worksheet returned an error telling me the query was too big, it took nearly 50 minutes before the error rose, and changing the warehouse size did not made it better