# Getting a SQL compilation error "Compilation memory exhausted." when trying to push an R data frame to Snowflake

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, dbi

I'm using [dbWriteTable](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbwritetable) to create a database table in Snowflake from R. This works nicely when I push a data frame of 350,000 rows, but fails with `SQL compilation error: Compilation memory exhausted.` when I try to push a table with around 3,000,000 rows.

I'd like to understand why this is happening. Obviously something to do with the size of the data frame, but I can't figure out what. When I save the larger data frame to a csv, it's less than 200MB.

I've looked at `showMethods("dbWriteTable", includeDefs = TRUE)` and reviewed the logs, but there's nothing obvious showing why this fails. This [Snowflake community post](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Handle-Compilation-Memory-Exhausted-error-in-Snowflake) suggests it's due to a complex query or TB size data sets. I don't have TBs of data, so maybe it's a query size issue? There's a [limit of 1MB](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-size-limits#limits-on-query-text-size) for the query size, but the data frame with 350,000 rows is much larger than this when saved as a csv, and I had no problems there.

To be clear this is the only code I'm running:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = myconn,
             name = table_id,
             value = my_df,
             overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you know how much memory the cloud/vm instance has available? Are you making a temporary table (which are often stored in memory but on disk, not sure about snowflake)? How many columns (might not matter)?

Comment: I would want to know 1. how complex is your SQL. if it has many tables involved, please try simple like `select * from mytab limit 350001`. 2. If simple sql works then, your query complexity is the problem. Reduce complexity, apply more filters, use stage tables etc.. 3. If this doesnt work then there must be some row limit somewhere preventing data to be pushed to snowflake. 4. Consider latency between your R client and Snowflake as well. Please note this seems to be problem with your R which cooks the SQL but again i am not sure since you can dump the data in csv.

Comment: @KoushikRoy there is no SQL query involved on my end. dbWriteTable might generate one, but the only code I'm running is dbWriteTable(conn = myconn, name = table_id, value = my_df, overwrite = TRUE)

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure how much memory is available. It's a Snowflake medium warehouse. I think it should have enough compute/ storage to deal with this. I don't intentionally create a temporary table, but maybe dbWriteTable does somehow? There are 5 columns in the smaller data frame and 6 in the larger data frame.

Comment: If you're using the `odbc` package (and possibly other drivers?), then the use of `dbWriteTable` (and friends) _does_ generate actual SQL, see https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/366. From that, though, another idea: are there any triggers/constraints on the table?

Comment: Yes, I am using the `odbc` package. The Snowflake driver is SnowflakeDSIIDriver. I also see `INSERT INTO` statements with `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` in my warehouse query history. I don't think there are any triggers or constraints on the table, at least none that I'm aware of.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66375356/3358272 and https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-size-limits

Answer (score 1):

The Snowflake odbc driver has various performance optimisations it can take advantage of when dealing with bulk datasets.

When inserting a large number of rows it will typically export the data to temporary gzipd csv file(s), [PUT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put) them to a temporary internal stage in Snowflake and then perform an efficient Insert process from the file(s).  You should be able to observe this behaviour by looking at Query History within the Snowsight UI, or you can run a query like this within R using your odbc session to return Query History.

```
select  QUERY_TEXT, TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME, START_TIME 
from  table(information_schema.query_history_by_session()) 
order by start_time desc;
```

You should see a series of SQL statements something like:

1. Drop Table ;
2. Create Table  ....
3. Put file:// ....   [1:n of these]
4. Insert Into  (col1,
   col2, ... coln) values (?,?,...?)
5. Commit

If you see something different it may be that your user does not have the required permissions to use the optimised method.  e.g. cannot create temporary stage.

There is an option that you can set to control the number of rows processed in each batch. You can check the setting using `getOption("odbc.batch_rows")`.

If you do not set this explicitly it should return NULL. When NULL, the behaviour is to execute a single INSERT statement from the data, containing all the rows to be inserted, and this could be exceeding memory and statement size limits.

If you set it explicitly (e.g. `options(odbc.batch_rows = 500000)`) the behaviour is to perform Inserts of the requested batch size.  In this case [3,4] above will repeat for each batch until all rows have been inserted.  You can use this to avoid the batch size being too large.

I used the following code to test this:

```
ncols <- 10
nrows <- 5000000
ncell <- nc * nr

data_for_ingest <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(ncell), ncol = ncols, nrow = nrows))

options(odbc.batch_rows = 5000000)

table_id <- DBI::Id(catalog = "SF_TEST", schema = "R_INGEST", table = sprintf("DATA_INGEST_%s_%s",nc,nr))

system.time(
   DBI::dbWriteTable(conn      = odbcCon,
                     name      = table_id,
                     value     = data_for_ingest,
                     overwrite = TRUE) )
```

I observed the following results:

| odbc.batch_rows | # Inserts | Seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 1 | 119 |
| 500000 | 10 | 156 |
| 1000000 | 5 | 128 |
| 2500000 | 2 | 122 |
| 5000000 | 1 | 99 |

Larger batch sizes are slightly more efficient, but might exceed memory limits.  Number of columns, size and data-type in the dataset will also have a bearing on performance and limits.

If your working with very large datasets that you want to load into Snowflake efficiently you can also export them to CSV or parquet, PUT them to a stage and use COPY to load them. e.g.

```
write.csv(data_for_ingest, paste0(tempdir(), "/","data_for_ingest.csv"), row.names=FALSE)

odbc::dbGetQuery(odbcCon, 'CREATE TABLE "DATA_INGEST_PUT_COPY" (
  "V1" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V2" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V3" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V4" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V5" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V6" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V7" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V8" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V9" DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "V10" DOUBLE PRECISION
  )')

odbc::dbGetQuery(odbcCon, 'CREATE STAGE my_int_stage')

odbc::dbGetQuery(odbcCon, paste0('PUT ', paste0('file://',tempdir(),'/','data_for_ingest.csv'), '@my_int_stage'))

odbc::dbGetQuery(odbcCon, "CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_csv_format
  TYPE = CSV
  FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
  SKIP_HEADER = 1
  NULL_IF = ('NULL', 'null')
  EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = true
  COMPRESSION = gzip;")

odbc::dbGetQuery(odbcCon, "COPY INTO DATA_INGEST_PUT_COPY FROM @my_int_stage FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = 'my_csv_format')")
```

You may need your Snowflake database administrator to provide your user/role with permissions to create some of these objects within your Snowflake account if your user does not have them already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the underlying cause (could be a few things), but one workaround might be to batch the uploads. For instance, assuming `con` (connection object) and `mtcars` (the dataset), and a batch size of `10` (artifically low).

Setup:

```r
### only if the table does not already exist
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "r2tmp", mtcars[0,], row.names = FALSE)

### proof it exists and is empty
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from r2tmp")
#  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

```r
rows <- 1:nrow(mtcars)
for (rn in split(rows, rows %/% 10)) DBI::dbAppendTable(con, "r2tmp", mtcars[rn,])
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from r2tmp")
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
# 11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
# 12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# 13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# 14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# 15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# 16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# 17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# 18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# 19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# 20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# 21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# 22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# 23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# 24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# 25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# 26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# 27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# 28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# 29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
# 30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# 31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# 32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

I suggest you start with a large batch size (perhaps `500000`?) and if it succeeds, run the rest of the code; if it also fails, dump down a lot (`100000`) and try again until the first append succeeds.

Comment: I tried a batch size of 500k, and it worked so I went up to 1 million. That worked too. I tried going to 2 million, but then it failed with the same error `SQL compilation error:
Compilation memory exhausted.` I can certainly use the smaller batch sizes as a work around, but I would really like to understand why the original code failed.